# New Bicycle - Chain making noise

Tags: chain

Hi I recently purchased a new bicycle. I have only been out on it twice and the chain is making a sort of clink and clunk noise. Is this common as its a new bike with new chain? Does the chain need to bed in and the noise will stop?

Please advise.

David

Comment: Note that you may be hearing spoke noise -- not uncommon with a new bike.

Comment: Some more information on the type of bike might be useful. If it's a derailleur bike the gear indexing might be poorly adjusted.

Comment: "I have a new product and something is wrong with it" -- honestly, the answer is to take it back to the shop and get them to fix it. Other answers help you learn, of course, but the real answer is to take it back to the shop. You paid them for a working bike, not a clinking clunking one.

Answer (score 1):

Chain 'bedding in' is not a thing. Most likely the rear derailleur indexing adjustment is a little off so the chain is not running true on each sprocket. The shift and brake cable do stretch a little, requiring adjustment after a few hours riding.

If you bought the bike at a bicycle store, take it back for a tune up. In the USA this is typically done for free. If you bought it at a department or big-box store, a local bike shop will do a tune up for you.

Comment: Tune-ups of new bikes are typically free in the UK, too.

Answer (score 0):

Not common at all. Unless the moving parts are not well lubed enough or the parts that are supposed to sturdy are not screwed well, the bike is probably defective.